# Trying to match partial numbers (6 numbers) in two columns of data

Tags: indexing

I would like to match 6 exact numbers in two columns of data to feed a positive match. In example

Column 1: 8565484844 would bring back a positive match for 484844.598. The function needs to somehow match when 6 digits are in sequential order, whether they have numbers in front of them or behind them.

Pretty lost on how to make it so 6 digits within a number brings up a positive match.

Thanks

Comment: Cast both numbers as String.  Check the first digit of the first number against each digit of the second number.  For each match, check if the next 5 digits of each number match.  Otherwise, match the second digit of the first number against each digit of the second number.  Continue until you've matched the last digit of the first number with the last digit of the second number.

Comment: jossm can you add the code what you have tried so far